# Concrete Repository class implements 2 interfaces, how to declare a variable now?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

My UserRepository looks like:

```
 public class UserRepository : Repository<User>, IUserRepository
```

Now how to I declare a variable using an interface, if I do:

```
IUserRepository repo = new UserRepository();
```

And then if I try and use a method that was declared in Repository, it obviously doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Update**

I changed things to this now:

```
public interface IRepository<T> { // methos here }

public interface IUserRepository : IRepository<IUser>
{
}


public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> { // impl of methods here }
```

And my UserRepository.cs is:

```
 public class UserRepository : Repository<User>, IUserRepository
 {
 }
```

Now even though the Repository has all the implementations of the methods, I can a build error in UserRepository.cs that lists all the methods that need to be implemented.

*(remember IUserRepository is empty thus far, only IRepository has methods)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an IRepository interface. Then have IUserRepository extend IRepository. That should fix  you up.

Comment: I tried this:  `public class UserRepository: Repository<User>, IUserRepository` and my interface is:  `public interface IUserRepository: IRepository<IUser>`.  But now it complains that all my methods are not implemented in UserRepository.cs

Comment: ok I had to change it to IUser instead of User in UserRepository then it worked, thanks!